# beans created by BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor not calling postconstruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

basically creating the genericBeanDefinition and adding to the bean factory on a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, when created the bean does not executes @PostConstruct methods.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Spring version: 4.3.3.RELEASE

Comment: Whether something is a bug or a feature is a matter of opinion.  You may want to ask the authors of the Spring framework.

Comment: Thanks for the answer john, I just want to know if that is my mistake and I'm missing a step so the postconstruct work, or if it should work and is not because of a bug in spring version (very unlikelly)

Comment: Perhaps this is the reason: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8269

Comment: It's possible, I found that bug as well, but since it was fixed on version 3.2 and I'm using 4.3 and I'm not using @Configuration annotation doesn't seem like. But i'm gonna look into. Thanks